# How would I filter the data returned from Slack to find active users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, slack-api

### Question

How would I filter the [user data](https://api.slack.com/types/user) returned from Slack to find **Active** Slack Users (e.g., users in our workgroup that we pay for)?

If a user is inactive for some time, they no longer cost us (thanks slack!). Also, we can remove people from our workgroup.

How do I filter down the `users.list` to a list of users we will be charged for? OR What elements from user.list will reveal active membership.

### Issue

I was filtering for users *not* deleted:

```
        const slackActiveAccounts = slackMembers
          .filter(member => member.deleted == false);
```

But users that have stayed inactive and no longer count against our billing will be found as `member.deleted: false`. So inactive and deleted are different.

### `user.list` json example

From the [Slack API documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list)

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "user": {
        "id": "W012A3CDE",
        "team_id": "T012AB3C4",
        "name": "spengler",
        "deleted": false,
        "color": "9f69e7",
        "real_name": "Egon Spengler",
        "tz": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "tz_label": "Pacific Daylight Time",
        "tz_offset": -25200,
        "profile": {
            "avatar_hash": "ge3b51ca72de",
            "status_text": "Print is dead",
            "status_emoji": ":books:",
            "status_expiration": 1502138999,
            "real_name": "Egon Spengler",
            "display_name": "spengler",
            "real_name_normalized": "Egon Spengler",
            "display_name_normalized": "spengler",
            "email": "spengler@ghostbusters.example.com",
            "image_24": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "image_32": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "image_48": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "image_72": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "image_192": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "image_512": "https://.../avatar/e3b51ca72dee4ef87916ae2b9240df50.jpg",
            "team": "T012AB3C4"
        },
        "is_admin": true,
        "is_owner": false,
        "is_primary_owner": false,
        "is_restricted": false,
        "is_ultra_restricted": false,
        "is_bot": false,
        "is_stranger": false,
        "updated": 1502138686,
        "is_app_user": false,
        "has_2fa": false,
        "locale": "en-US"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the API method [`team.billableInfo`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.billableInfo) might be more helpful for your case.

> This method lists billable information for each user on the team.
>   Currently this consists solely of whether the user is subject to
>   billing per Slack's Fair Billing policy.

Or if you want to get the list of currently "active" users I would suggest checking out the API method [`team.accessLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs). (payed tier only)

> This method is used to retrieve the "access logs" for users on a
>   workspace.
>
> Each access log entry represents a user accessing Slack from a
>   specific user, IP address, and user agent combination.

The method `users.list` does not contain any information about user activity. `deleted` means that a user has been manually deactivated by an admin and can no longer log-in. In general an  admin can not delete a user in Slack, only deactivate them.

Comment: How often or when is billing updated?  Reading this in the Slack Documentation: _A billing_active status of true indicates that the user is eligible per billing per Slack's Fair Billing policy. The billing_active status is computed periodically and the values returned by this API reflect the most recently computed status and should not be interpreted as a real-time view of each user's billing_active status._

Comment: I'm finding the API is showing two users at active, while the _Manage Members_ view shows those users inactive. What else would indicate billing users as they show up in the Admin panel?